# ios timer only run once

Tags: ios, timer

```
-(void)btnClick:(id)sender

{
    NSLog(@"btnClick");


    dispatch_queue_t queue=dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
    dispatch_source_t timer=dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), 2*NSEC_PER_SEC, 1*NSEC_PER_SEC); 

    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.label1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", arc4random_uniform(1000000)];
        });
    });

    dispatch_resume(timer);
}
```

when i click the button ,label1.text.value only display one time,but i want it to be updated every 2 second of a time. please help me ``

Comment: Where is code of your timer method? please also put it here

Comment: Why don't you directly let the timer dispatch to the main queue instead to some global concurrent queue just to re-dispatch to the main queue? Doing it that way has no advantages at all but can cause a back log on the main queue and that would have huge disadvantages. Also you should not use  `0` in places where constants are expected (use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT`). And don't use *walltime* if you only want relative time intervals (use `dispatch_time()` not `dispatch_walltime()` unless you really want a walltime and in your case you don't).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(yourMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

And in `yourMethod` do this:

```
-(void)yourMethod{
    Self.label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", arc4random_uniform(1000000)];
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Might want to add a variable to catch that NSTimer (invalid + set to nil), otherwise, the view controller could potentially not dealloc during popViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You can create timer as bellow

```
//Define member varialbe for timer in header file
NSTimer* timerForLocationUpdate;

//Call createTimer to create timer that will execute in each 1 min

- (void) createTimer
{
    timerForLocationUpdate = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 /*Number of seconds*/
                                                              target:self
                                                            selector:@selector(updateLocation)
                                                            userInfo:nil
                                                             repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timerForLocationUpdate
                                 forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

//Method is called in each 1 min
- (void) updateLocation
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `timer` is a local variable, it will be released when `-(void)btnClick:(id)sender` finishes.

so try to catch `timer` as a Class variable or Instance variable or Static variable.

eg:

```
-(void)btnClick:(id)sender

{
    NSLog(@"btnClick");

    static dispatch_source_t timer;

    dispatch_queue_t queue=dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
    timer=dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), 2*NSEC_PER_SEC, 1*NSEC_PER_SEC); 

    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.label1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", arc4random_uniform(1000000)];
        });
    });

    dispatch_resume(timer);
}
```

it will work :)